# Unable to read local file in sparkStreaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

i'm tring to read local file in sparkStreaming ,but i got problem . I can't get the data. I start sparkStreaming first then move a new file to dataDirector,but it also doesn't work. And there is no error in the program .And I've tried both local and cluster modes in linux ,it doesn't work too.But it can work when HDFS dataDirector get a new file. SomeOne who can hep me? Thanks! Then there's my code.

```
public class SparkStreamingTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
        conf.setMaster("local[2]")
            //.setMaster("spark://192.168.170.135:7077")
                    .setAppName("testSparkStreaming");

        JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, Durations.seconds(5));
        //JavaDStream<String> lines = jssc.textFileStream("file:///home/sparkStreaming/data");
        JavaDStream<String> lines = jssc.textFileStream("e:\\testFile");
        //JavaDStream<String> lines = jssc.textFileStream("hdfs://192.168.170.135:9000/sparkStreaming/data");

        JavaDStream<String> words =  lines.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {

            @Override
            public Iterator<String> call(String line) throws Exception {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return Arrays.asList(line.split(" ")).iterator();
            }
        });
        lines.print();
        jssc.start();
        jssc.awaitTermination();
```

I start the program then move a new file to dataDirector ,Following is the log.No data is available,Is the textFileStream method of spark streaming not supporting read local files?

```
    14:21:55.001 [JobGenerator] DEBUG o.a.s.s.dstream.FileInputDStream - Time 1502086915000 ms is valid
    14:21:55.001 [JobGenerator] DEBUG o.a.s.s.dstream.FileInputDStream - Getting new files for time 1502086915000, ignoring files older than 1502086855000
    14:21:55.002 [JobGenerator] DEBUG o.a.s.s.dstream.FileInputDStream - file:/e:/testFile/test2.txt ignored as mod time 1501816119160 <= ignore time 1502086855000
    14:21:55.002 [JobGenerator] INFO  o.a.s.s.dstream.FileInputDStream - Finding new files took 1 ms
    14:21:55.002 [JobGenerator] DEBUG o.a.s.s.dstream.FileInputDStream - # cached file times = 1
    14:21:55.002 [JobGenerator] INFO  o.a.s.s.dstream.FileInputDStream - New files at time 1502086915000 ms:
14:28:40.009 [JobGenerator] DEBUG org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner - +++ Cleaning closure <function1> (org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$$anonfun$textFileStream$1$$anonfun$apply$2) +++
14:28:40.010 [JobGenerator] DEBUG org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner -  + declared fields: 1
14:28:40.010 [JobGenerator] DEBUG org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner -      public static final long org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$$anonfun$textFileStream$1$$anonfun$apply$2.serialVersionUID
14:28:40.010 [JobGenerator] DEBUG org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner -  + declared methods: 2
14:28:40.010 [JobGenerator] DEBUG org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner -      public final java.lang.Object org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$$anonfun$textFileStream$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(java.lang.Object)
14:28:40.010 [JobGenerator] DEBUG org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner -      public final java.lang.String org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$$anonfun$textFileStream$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(scala.Tuple2)
14:28:40.010 [JobGenerator] DEBUG org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner -  + inner classes: 0
14:28:40.010 [JobGenerator] DEBUG org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner -  + outer classes: 0
14:28:40.010 [JobGenerator] DEBUG org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner -  + outer objects: 0
14:28:40.011 [JobGenerator] DEBUG org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner -  + populating accessed fields because this is the starting closure
14:28:40.012 [JobGenerator] DEBUG org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner -  + fields accessed by starting closure: 0
14:28:40.012 [JobGenerator] DEBUG org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner -  + there are no enclosing objects!
14:28:40.012 [JobGenerator] DEBUG org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner -  +++ closure <function1> (org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$$anonfun$textFileStream$1$$anonfun$apply$2) is now cleaned +++
14:28:40.013 [JobGenerator] DEBUG o.a.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph - Generated 1 jobs for time 1502087320000 ms
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1502087320000 ms
-------------------------------------------

14:28:40.014 [JobGenerator] INFO  o.a.s.s.scheduler.JobScheduler - Added jobs for time 1502087320000 ms
```

Comment: Looks liked it worked to me... `file:/e:/testFile/test2.txt ignored`

Comment: I've seen that but it doesn't show the data..so it make me depressed

Comment: Is it possible that the jar has a problem?

Comment: Your files need to be modified after the steam starts, not just moved

Comment: That's what I did, but it didn't work

Comment: JavaRDD<String> lines = jsc.textFile("E:\\testFile\\test2.txt");   This works normally,but i want to use spark Streaming

Comment: It should work. Maybe try increasing the duration. Create a brand new file after your stream starts, then move it into the directory

Comment: That's what i do,but it doesn't work

Comment: are you using a Mac?

Comment: The above code is run on Windows,I also tried to  pack it into a jar and spark-submit it in linux, but there's no data on the display